# Bilingual Latin/Greek and English texts online?

Tags: latin-to-english-translation, ancient-greek, resource-request, greek-to-english-translation, source

I'm currently about halfway through Ανάβασις by Ξενοφών.

I think possibly I might have a crack at Herodotus Histories after that.

I found a great source for a bilingual edition of Ανάβασις in Greek and English [here](https://www.mikrosapoplous.gr/t2t.htm) (first book of Ανάβασις in table format [here](https://www.mikrosapoplous.gr/xenophon/anb1d10.htm)). This format given for Ανάβασις is perfect: a table, with one column in Greek and the other in English. Unfortunately most of the other items on that page are not bilingual editions, and the list also doesn't include Ἡρόδοτος.

With Ανάβασις I've been able to download the HTML tables and convert them into Word documents, with 2 columns. Then I've made the right column (English) very very pale grey (on white background), so that I can only look at it when I really need to. This really works for me as I plough through Kyros's shenanigans (he's just died, so it doesn't look too promising currently). For each sentence I can make my little vocab list, in a cell in a table in the file.

I found [this site](https://penelope.uchicago.edu/Thayer/E/Roman/Texts/Herodotus/home.html) with a bilingual Ἡρόδοτος Ἱστορίαι (Ἡρόδοτ**ου** Ἱστορίαι **;**). But the format there is not particularly downloadable as things seem to be on separate pages for the two languages. It may be the best there is publicly available, and I can see that it'd be possible to construct similar two-column tables in Word documents. It'd take a bit more time though.

Does anyone know of any other sites? I'd be interested in bilingual Latin-English sites for Latin authors too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Herodotus in particular, you can use [Sacred Texts](https://sacred-texts.com/cla/hh/hh1000.htm), which has parallel columns. The translation is by Macaulay 1890, but it's still fairly readable.

Unfortunately, they don't have a lot of other authors in that format. The ones that have the parallel format are the [Argonautica](https://sacred-texts.com/cla/argo/index.htm), [Lucian's True Story](https://sacred-texts.com/cla/luc/true/index.htm), [the works of Caesar and Pseudo-Caesar](https://sacred-texts.com/cla/jcsr/index.htm), and [Tacitus' works](https://sacred-texts.com/cla/tac/index.htm). Others have it formatted unusually. [Homer's Greek](https://sacred-texts.com/cla/homer/greek/index.htm), is separate. [Sappho's](https://sacred-texts.com/cla/usappho/sph02.htm) has the Greek first and the English following it. Some have no accompanying original text at all.

A newer (relatively speaking) site is [Scaife viewer](https://scaife.perseus.org/reader/urn:cts:greekLit:tlg0012.tlg001.perseus-grc2:1.1-1.7?right=perseus-eng3). I've found, at least in Firefox, the site is sluggish and a bit buggy. Although it's less user friendly, they have most texts that you'll want available.

Downloading the text from Perseus' [Github account](https://github.com/PerseusDL) though means that making a parallel document yourself isn't too difficult.

Comment: The Herodotus is perfect. With a bit of luck that'll keep me out of mischief for a while. I think the WCA (Worldwide Classics Authority) should use some of its vast financial resources to produce such bilingual online texts in table form for ALL classical texts since the dawn of writing, e.g. at Gutenberg, if only for the good of humanity.

Comment: @mikerodent Check my edit - you might find Scaife useful. I don't love the site and so I don't use it frequently, but it should also scratch your itch.

Comment: Scaife looks like a pretty good project ... I just looked at Pindar in Greek with English pretty much aligned. And a useful automated word list. And massive amounts of texts. Good resource for the future.